# jQuery show/hide toggles firing only at large screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery

The URL is http://zacimoveis.vistatemporario.com.br/nossa-equipe

The issue is with the blue description box that shows up when hovering the images. It works just fine for screen sizes larger than 980px, but nothing happens on < 980px screens, be it on tablets/mobiles or in desktops.

I've tried toggle(), slideToggle() and straight up show() and hide() and searched around for tons of different variations.

Here's the current version of the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $(".membro").hover(function() {
var pessoa = $(this).attr('id');
$('#txt' + pessoa).toggle()
})});
```

(No error message shows up in the console.)

Comment: on tablets you have to click on picture to see the box.

Comment: Clicking doesn't work either....

Answer (score 0):

Think the event is the problem here, you are using .hover. Don't think that will work on your tables/phones etc. AS a matter of fact there is no .hover on  tablets/mobiles as i remember.

You might need to do something along the lines of

```
$(".membro").on("hover touchstart",function(evt){
   // whatever
})
```

OR you might need to add a bit more CSS classes. There seem to be a grid system following the bootstrap approach which might be interfering with your positioning as well.

Comment: The problem is in the screen size, not in the type of the device. If you try reducing the browser size in a desktop computer, the toggle will fail just like in mobiles/tablets.

Comment: The positioning might be the key. I'll try changing some CSS styles.